# ffmpeg converting .vob to .mp4 --- colors are washed out

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I am very new to ffmpeg. Currently I am trying to convert old family movies from vob to mp4.
After getting some help I used this command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1998.vob -codec:v libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac -movflags +faststart 1998.mp4
```

Two things that still bug me. The output is almost 20% larger than the input and the colors are washed out. Although the movies are old and of low quality (grainy, rather flat colors, ...) the colors in the output movie are less intense than in the original one. Larger file size would be ok for me but do you have any idea which part of my command might cause the color issue?

```
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mpeg, from '1995.vob':
  Duration: 00:00:14.64, start: 0.232178, bitrate: 1676252 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
  Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 704x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 9548800/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
File '999.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] using SAR=12/11
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] 264 - core 161 r3049 55d517b - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=17.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '999.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top coded first (swapped)), 704x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 aac
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   frame=   59 fps=0.0 q=22.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate=1024.2kbits/frame=   75 fps= 72 q=22.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:02.68 bitrate=3120.9kbits/frame=   95 fps= 61 q=22.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:03.45 bitrate=4854.6kbits/frame=  112 fps= 54 q=22.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:04.18 bitrate=5517.2kbits/frame=  131 fps= 51 q=22.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:04.92 bitrate=6809.0kbits/frame=  149 fps= 48 q=22.0 size=    4864kB time=00:00:05.65 bitrate=7048.3kbits/frame=  169 fps= 47 q=22.0 size=    6144kB time=00:00:06.42 bitrate=7838.3kbits/frame=  183 fps= 44 q=22.0 size=    6912kB time=00:00:07.04 bitrate=8043.1kbits/frame=  203 fps= 43 q=22.0 size=    7936kB time=00:00:07.80 bitrate=8326.3kbits/frame=  221 fps= 42 q=22.0 size=    8960kB time=00:00:08.51 bitrate=8623.2kbits/frame=  240 fps= 42 q=22.0 size=    9984kB time=00:00:09.28 bitrate=8813.5kbits/frame=  261 fps= 41 q=22.0 size=   11264kB time=00:00:10.06 bitrate=9164.0kbits/frame=  278 fps= 40 q=22.0 size=   12288kB time=00:00:10.81 bitrate=9306.9kbits/frame=  294 fps= 40 q=22.0 size=   13568kB time=00:00:11.45 bitrate=9702.3kbits/frame=  311 fps= 39 q=22.0 size=   14592kB time=00:00:12.09 bitrate=9882.4kbits/frame=  329 fps= 39 q=22.0 size=   15616kB time=00:00:12.86 bitrate=9944.5kbits/frame=  347 fps= 39 q=22.0 size=   16640kB time=00:00:13.56 bitrate=10046.8kbitsframe=  366 fps= 38 q=22.0 size=   17920kB time=00:00:14.33 bitrate=10240.0kbitsframe=  385 fps= 38 q=22.0 size=   19200kB time=00:00:15.12 bitrate=10398.9kbitsframe=  400 fps= 38 q=22.0 size=   20224kB time=00:00:15.63 bitrate=10594.9kbitsframe=  418 fps= 38 q=22.0 size=   21504kB time=00:00:16.34 bitrate=10780.1kbitsframe=  431 fps= 37 q=22.0 size=   22528kB time=00:00:16.89 bitrate=10922.7kbitsframe=  447 fps= 37 q=22.0 size=   23808kB time=00:00:17.53 bitrate=11122.0kbitsframe=  466 fps= 37 q=22.0 size=   25088kB time=00:00:18.26 bitrate=11254.5kbitsframe=  479 fps= 36 q=22.0 size=   25856kB time=00:00:18.81 bitrate=11257.1kbitsframe=  497 fps= 36 q=22.0 size=   27136kB time=00:00:19.54 bitrate=11375.8kbitsframe=  513 fps= 36 q=22.0 size=   28416kB time=00:00:20.16 bitrate=11546.8kbitsframe=  530 fps= 36 q=22.0 size=   29440kB time=00:00:20.92 bitrate=11523.9kbitsframe=  546 fps= 36 q=22.0 size=   30464kB time=00:00:21.56 bitrate=11570.9kbitsframe=  564 fps= 36 q=22.0 size=   31744kB time=00:00:22.10 bitrate=11766.1kbitsframe=  580 fps= 36 q=19.0 size=   32512kB time=00:00:22.80 bitrate=11678.8kbitsframe=  598 fps= 36 q=22.0 size=   33792kB time=00:00:23.57 bitrate=11743.1kbitsframe=  614 fps= 35 q=22.0 size=   34560kB time=00:00:24.25 bitrate=11672.0kbitsframe=  630 fps= 35 q=22.0 size=   35328kB time=00:00:24.85 bitrate=11644.6kbitsframe=  646 fps= 35 q=22.0 size=   36096kB time=00:00:25.42 bitrate=11628.3kbitsframe=  662 fps= 35 q=22.0 size=   37376kB time=00:00:26.17 bitrate=11697.1kbitsframe=  682 fps= 35 q=22.0 size=   38400kB time=00:00:26.90 bitrate=11693.6kbitsframe=  699 fps= 35 q=22.0 size=   39424kB time=00:00:27.66 bitrate=11672.2kbitsframe=  719 fps= 35 q=22.0 size=   40704kB time=00:00:28.41 bitrate=11734.5kbitsframe=  736 fps= 35 q=22.0 size=   41728kB time=00:00:29.14 bitrate=11730.3kbitsframe=  753 fps= 35 q=22.0 size=   42752kB time=00:00:29.71 bitrate=11785.2kbitsframe=  764 fps= 35 q=22.0 size=   43520kB time=00:00:30.20 bitrate=11802.0kbitsframe=  776 fps= 35 q=22.0 size=   44544kB time=00:00:30.72 bitrate=11878.4kbitsframe=  786 fps= 34 q=22.0 size=   45312kB time=00:00:31.06 bitrate=11950.4kbitsframe=  799 fps= 34 q=22.0 size=   46080kB time=00:00:31.57 bitrate=11955.9kbitsframe=  815 fps= 34 q=22.0 size=   47104kB time=00:00:32.14 bitrate=12002.6kbitsframe=  830 fps= 34 q=22.0 size=   48128kB time=00:00:32.78 bitrate=12024.2kbitsframe=  839 fps= 33 q=22.0 size=   48640kB time=00:00:33.15 bitrate=12019.2kbitsframe=  847 fps= 33 q=22.0 size=   49152kB time=00:00:33.49 bitrate=12021.9kbitsframe=  858 fps= 33 q=22.0 size=   49920kB time=00:00:33.98 bitrate=12033.5kbitsframe=  867 fps= 32 q=22.0 size=   50688kB time=00:00:34.30 bitrate=12104.6kbitsframe=  880 fps= 32 q=22.0 size=   51456kB time=00:00:34.88 bitrate=12085.1kbitsframe=  898 fps= 32 q=22.0 size=   52480kB time=00:00:35.54 bitrate=12096.2kbitsframe=  913 fps= 32 q=22.0 size=   53504kB time=00:00:36.18 bitrate=12114.1kbitsframe=  923 fps= 32 q=22.0 size=   54016kB time=00:00:36.54 bitrate=12108.7kbitsframe=  940 fps= 32 q=22.0 size=   55040kB time=00:00:37.20 bitrate=12118.9kbitsframe=  958 fps= 32 q=22.0 size=   55808kB time=00:00:37.90 bitrate=12059.8kbitsframe=  975 fps= 32 q=22.0 size=   56832kB time=00:00:38.61 bitrate=12057.2kbitsframe=  994 fps= 32 q=22.0 size=   58112kB time=00:00:39.38 bitrate=12088.3kbitsframe= 1012 fps= 32 q=22.0 size=   59136kB time=00:00:40.02 bitrate=12104.6kbitsframe= 1026 fps= 32 q=22.0 size=   59904kB time=00:00:40.64 bitrate=12075.1kbitsframe= 1038 fps= 31 q=22.0 size=   60928kB time=00:00:41.21 bitrate=12109.9kbitsframe= 1046 fps= 31 q=22.0 size=   61440kB time=00:00:41.53 bitrate=12117.6kbitsframe= 1057 fps= 31 q=22.0 size=   61952kB time=00:00:41.87 bitrate=12119.0kbitsframe= 1071 fps= 31 q=22.0 size=   62976kB time=00:00:42.45 bitrate=12152.2kbitsframe= 1083 fps= 31 q=22.0 size=   63488kB time=00:00:42.90 bitrate=12123.0kbitsframe= 1096 fps= 31 q=22.0 size=   64256kB time=00:00:43.41 bitrate=12125.0kbitsframe= 1110 fps= 31 q=22.0 size=   65280kB time=00:00:44.09 bitrate=12127.5kbitsframe= 1126 fps= 31 q=22.0 size=   66048kB time=00:00:44.62 bitrate=12123.5kbitsframe= 1131 fps= 30 q=19.0 size=   66560kB time=00:00:44.86 bitrate=12153.6kbitsframe= 1147 fps= 30 q=22.0 size=   67584kB time=00:00:45.46 bitrate=12178.4kbitsframe= 1155 fps= 30 q=22.0 size=   68096kB time=00:00:45.88 bitrate=12156.6kbitsframe= 1167 fps= 30 q=22.0 size=   68864kB time=00:00:46.33 bitrate=12174.9kbitsframe= 1175 fps= 30 q=22.0 size=   69376kB time=00:00:46.59 bitrate=12198.0kbitsframe= 1184 fps= 30 q=22.0 size=   70144kB time=00:00:46.93 bitrate=12243.3kbitsframe= 1196 fps= 30 q=22.0 size=   70912kB time=00:00:47.44 bitrate=12243.8kbitsframe= 1211 fps= 30 q=22.0 size=   71936kB time=00:00:48.06 bitrate=12260.7kbitsframe= 1226 fps= 30 q=22.0 size=   73216kB time=00:00:48.66 bitrate=12325.7kbitsframe= 1240 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   73984kB time=00:00:49.17 bitrate=12325.3kbitsframe= 1256 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   75264kB time=00:00:49.85 bitrate=12366.9kbitsframe= 1271 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   76032kB time=00:00:50.43 bitrate=12350.4kbitsframe= 1280 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   76800kB time=00:00:50.81 bitrate=12380.9kbitsframe= 1288 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   77312kB time=00:00:51.13 bitrate=12385.4kbitsframe= 1295 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   77824kB time=00:00:51.39 bitrate=12405.3kbitsframe= 1303 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   78080kB time=00:00:51.73 bitrate=12364.0kbitsframe= 1316 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   78848kB time=00:00:52.28 bitrate=12353.2kbitsframe= 1331 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   79872kB time=00:00:52.86 bitrate=12377.3kbitsframe= 1349 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   80896kB time=00:00:53.56 bitrate=12371.2kbitsframe= 1364 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   81920kB time=00:00:54.14 bitrate=12394.5kbitsframe= 1379 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   82944kB time=00:00:54.74 bitrate=12412.5kbitsframe= 1396 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   83968kB time=00:00:55.38 bitrate=12420.5kbitsframe= 1417 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   84992kB time=00:00:56.27 bitrate=12371.9kbitsframe= 1438 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   86016kB time=00:00:57.10 bitrate=12338.5kbitsframe= 1458 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   87040kB time=00:00:57.92 bitrate=12310.6kbitsframe= 1478 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   88064kB time=00:00:58.64 bitrate=12301.4kbitsframe= 1498 fps= 29 q=22.0 size=   89088kB time=00:00:59.47 bitrate=12270.4kbits[mp4 @ 0x7ff666813200] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame= 1500 fps= 28 q=-1.0 Lsize=   91853kB time=00:00:59.98 bitrate=12543.2kbits/s speed=1.13x    
video:90866kB audio:941kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.049858%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] frame I:12    Avg QP:18.57  size:116766
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] frame P:426   Avg QP:20.52  size: 87768
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] frame B:1062  Avg QP:23.56  size: 51088
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] consecutive B-frames:  2.5%  6.4%  9.0% 82.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] mb I  I16..4:  1.0% 87.7% 11.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] mb P  I16..4:  0.5% 23.0%  4.2%  P16..4: 25.2% 30.8% 16.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  1.3%  0.6%  B16..8: 37.5% 21.2%  9.4%  direct:28.6%  skip: 1.4%  L0:31.5% L1:22.8% BI:45.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] 8x8 transform intra:80.8% inter:75.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 97.5% 95.0% 63.3% inter: 90.0% 62.4% 12.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] i16 v,h,dc,p: 36% 46%  6% 12%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 14% 16% 25%  5%  6%  7%  7%  8% 12%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 10% 29% 12%  6%  7%  6% 10%  7% 13%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] i8c dc,h,v,p: 36% 30% 20% 14%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] Weighted P-Frames: Y:29.3% UV:14.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] ref P L0: 39.8% 15.4% 21.2% 19.9%  3.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] ref B L0: 76.4% 19.1%  4.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] ref B L1: 90.7%  9.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff666814400] kb/s:12406.19
[aac @ 0x7ff666815c00] Qavg: 181.322
```

Comment: Add `-t 60` to encode a 1 minute segment and show the complete log.

Comment: Which part of the received text makes up the log?

Comment: All of the text.

Comment: Ok, updated my post

Comment: `-crf 17` or so is "visually lossless" so the resulting bitrate is going to be high. `-crf 23` should be about half the size and you may not notice that much of a difference given the already low quality of the input. As for the color difference, what player are you using? Does it look bad in other players too?